# Patching cached js bundles in the browser: How to or can we deploy delta / patches in big websites?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, frontend, patch

I was reading an article on git ".patch" files so was wondering if we can do something similar for big websites as well. This is particularly useful for the scenario when about 95% of the js bundle remains unchanged and you want to deploy the remaining 5% changes to your users via a delta update. So say if your js bundle was 6MB, the delta / patch file would be around ~300kB.

I had a hunch that the preferred approach would be to have some native browser API which will apply patch to the existing js bundle and then proceed normally. The benefit to the user is having to download just 300kB instead of the complete 6MB again. Nothing special, android apps and minor updates to various desktop apps use some form the the same strategy as a norm.

But to my surprise I couldn't come across any such API or mechanism. Is it that I couldn't find it and need to work on my Googling skills or does it not exist? If yes, what is the API called and if no, why does it not exist?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no built in api in browsers for this. But you could accomplish it by

1. Using the same text diffing library on frontend and backend (provided you have Node.js installed somewhere in your backend, like
   https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff
2. Combining this with using the Cache interface (from a service-worker if you want) and modifying cached response objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache OR *more
   old-school*, fetching the scripts, storing them in localStorage and
   create data-urls for them.

*Do note*: You're giving yourself/your team some/a lot(?) of extra work when it comes to the backend, because you would have to checkout each release version of the code (from git) and create a patch between it and all previous release versions and store those patches on the server. Then if you want to be able to automatically patch any 'downloaded' version, the frontend would have to send a version number to the server and the get the correct patch back... So it seems like **some** serious work to set up this system without glitches...

However, with the event of almost all modern web-servers serving data through http2 (or even http3) that can have 100:s of parallell requests downloading at once (as opposed to around 6 per domain in http1.1) you could argue that:

- We should stop bundling JS so much and instead serve small files. (However this would require you to change the default bundling settings for dev/build libraries such as CRA, Vite etc.) On the other hand this wouldn't solve the case of multiple small changes across several files, but work well as long as only a few of the files changes per release.